# Cocoapods not linking correctly for 3rd, 4th target (Xcode 7 beta 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm having a problem with Cocoapods and Xcode 7 beta 6: I have a project with three different test targets (tests, UITests, IntegrationTests). My pods seem to be working just fine with the first target ("tests") but the other targets are having problems:

- Everything builds just fine if I don't reference any of the Cocoapods in the latter two targets.
- However, when I try to use one of the pods (XCGLogger in this case), I get linker errors.
- I checked the build phases, and found that `Embed Pods Frameworks` was missing from both targets, so I manually added it.
- After doing this and cleaning, deleting derived data, the problem still exists.

Screenshot is attached that shows the linker error. Again this only happens if I try to use the XCGLogger in the latter two targets. It works fine in the first target.

[image: Linker error on some targets]

Just to be thorough... here's the Podfile I'm using:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'Glimpulse' do
  pod "SwiftSpinner", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftSpinner.git'
  pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
  pod 'GRValidation', '~> 0.2'
end

target 'GlimpulseTests' do
  pod "SwiftSpinner", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftSpinner.git'
  pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
  pod "Nimble", :git => 'https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod "Quick", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/Quick.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod 'GRValidation', '~> 0.2'
#  pod "SwiftCheck", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftCheck.git', :branch => 'swift-develop'
end

target 'GlimpulseUITests' do
  pod "SwiftSpinner", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftSpinner.git'
  pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
  pod "Nimble", :git => 'https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod "Quick", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/Quick.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod 'GRValidation', '~> 0.2'
#  pod "SwiftCheck", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftCheck.git', :branch => 'swift-develop'
end

target 'GlimpulseIntegrationTests' do
  pod "SwiftSpinner", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftSpinner.git'
  pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
  pod "Nimble", :git => 'https://github.com/Quick/Nimble.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod "Quick", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/Quick.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
  pod 'GRValidation', '~> 0.2'
#  pod "SwiftCheck", :git => 'https://github.com/zbeckman/SwiftCheck.git', :branch => 'swift-develop'
end

link_with 'GlimpulseUITests'
link_with 'GlimpulseIntegrationTests'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha. Ok, I think I figured it out, after much pain and suffering with deleting, recreating, `pod install`ing, and repeating... and fiddling with Xcode targets. My findings:

**Cocoapods 0.38.2 does not like Xcode 7 beta 6's new "iOS UI Testing Bundle" target type.**

The main problem is evident when setting up the new target and running `pod install`. The install appears to run fine but if you look at the build phases, the `Embed pods frameworks` phase is missing. However, if I manually create this phase (adjusting the paths as appropriate for the target), it does build.

**BUT...** Something weird still happens. The errors shown above (regarding linking for the current architecture) *still occur.* And here's the strangest part: If I change the target to use 'Build for active architecture only: **NO**' then everything works just fine. I don't get this last bit, because the pods should only be built for the current architecture. However... if the integration is whacked then... OK, who knows, maybe it gets fixed in the next Cocoapods release.

One other disappointing discovery: The new UI Test target type does *not* appear to support the `@testable` feature. Bummer. Hope they add that into the final release of Xcode 7...

Comment: We are having this same problem with the current version of Xcode, if you have any ideas, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this format for your `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'firstTarget', :exclusive => false do
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SwiftSpinner', '~> 0.7'
pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Nimble', '2.0.0-rc.3'
pod 'Quick', '~> 0.6'
pod 'GRValidation', '~> 0.2'
end

... repeat for every target
```

Find the `pod` syntaxes at `cocoapods.org`.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but this is not the problem. The root issue is something to do with the build but only for two of my targets: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: Yes, I did, except adjusting for using the target git branch of course. No difference... thinking perhaps if I delete the target, clean, delete derived data, rebuild everything with a new target... hopefully!

Comment: Groan. Ok, well... after deleting the target, clearing derived data, setting it all up again, tinkering with it for half an hour to get it to compile right, FINALLY one of the targets is good. Now if I can just remember what I did to fix it... so I can repeat on the other target. Started with deleting the target so... ;)

Comment: try to uninstall the pods first by typing `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods 0.38.2 has problem with xcode 7 as said above. i have faced this problem and fixed it by downgrading the the cocoapods version to 0.35.0. use gem uninstall cocoapods in terminal to uninstall.